# Using templates or inheriting constructors in C++

Tags: class, templates, c++11

Say I have this base class:

```
class Foo public: std::exception
{
    public:
        // printf()-style parms are formatted with vsnprintf() into a message
        Foo( const char * format, ... );
        // lots more stuff in this class not relevant to this example
};
```

Now I have a need to use this as a base exception class in dozens of places.  The catch() clause can then be written to catch just the base, or some derived class as required.

What I'd like to do is keep the dozens of new class definition very simple.  I'm reading up on inherited constructors in C++11, and I think something along these lines is needed:

```
class A : public Foo { public: using Foo::Foo; };
class B : public Foo { public: using Foo::Foo; };
```

The problem is this project is also compiled in Windows using Microsoft Visual Studio, and as far as I can tell [it doesn't support inheriting constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Is there another obvious way to do this keeping the derived classes relatively simple?  Perhaps with templates?  I'm a newbie when it comes to templates and could use a kick in the right direction if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Do the classes literally differ only in names, like `A` and `B` in your example (which can make sense for exception types), or will they contain other differences that just usually don't affect the constructors?

Comment: Why can't you just specify a call to Foos constructor from A or B - you shouldn't call Foos constructor directly

Comment: I mean from the constructors of A and B, you can invoke Foos constructor

Comment: Because the constructor uses ... to specify variable number of parameters, I cannot easily "duplicate" that constructor from A or B.  If that isn't the case, please post an example of how to do that, cause I don't know how.

Comment: @BenS correct, there are no other differences.

Comment: When providing `Foo(const char* format, ...);`, provide also `Foo(const char* format, va_list args);`

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
class Base : public std::exception {};

template <int UNUSED>
class Foo : public Base
{
    public:
        // printf()-style parms are formatted with vsnprintf() into a message
        Foo( const char * format, ... );
        // lots more stuff in this class not relevant to this example
};

typedef Foo<1> A;
typedef Foo<2> B;
```

Edited to add a base class to be able to catch all Foo exceptions.

Comment: How is this useful? Yeah, if he needs lots of functionally identical types and no functionality in `Base`, it should work great.

Comment: @Potatoswatter that's exactly what he's asking for.

Comment: These are exception classes. The only thing they differ by is their name. This is how exceptions are almost always done. One of OP's requirements is to be able to catch all `Foo` exceptions. A catch block for `Base` accomplishes this in my scheme.

Comment: @Potatoswatter `Foo<1>` and `Foo<2>` are NOT the same type.

Comment: Exception classes usually don't implement much extra functionality, but tying yourself to exactly zero doesn't seem like such good architecture. At the least, you might want some kind of hierarchy.

Comment: @Potatoswatter All the functionality is in `Foo<>`. `Base`'s ONLY purpose is to serve as a parent catch-all. If the catch-all wasn't a requirement then `Base` can disappear. You're confusing your hierarchy with mine.

Comment: my hierarchy is `exception -> Base -> A,B`. It's just that `A` and `B` are template specializations of `Foo` to save on boilerplate.

Comment: Implementing the functionality in Foo doesn't mean new Foo's may have different extra functionality; there is no room to add functionality by specialization *because* specialization now requires reimplementing everything. I never suggested a hierarchy.

Comment: @Potatoswatter yes you did, 4 comments up!

Comment: NEW FOOS ARE NOT SUPPOSED TO HAVE ANY NEW FUNCTIONALITY! OP says: "there are no other differences [besides name]" right in the comments!

Comment: I suggested that the user might want *some* hierarchy, I didn't suggest what form it might take. This is limited to just one `Base` class unless you declare something else… and then back at square 1.

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't read those comments. Again, it's an architectural issue: do you want a structure which will never extend to support new things?

Comment: OP doesn't mention that as a requirement, his intended use case doesn't suggest that it would be necessary, but if it was, it would still be no different in my scheme than any other. I really don't see what the problem is. Either way, it's nighttime where I am so I'm done here.

Answer (score 1):

The point of an inheriting constructor is to inherit many constructors, and your example only has one. Aside from that…

Yes, there is an idiomatic workaround when inheriting constructors don't work, due to poor support or perhaps just some quirk of what they do. You can use perfect forwarding instead.

```
template< typename ... a >
A( a && ... arg ) : Foo( std::forward< a >( arg ) ... ) {}
```

The downsides are that conversions are applied at the `Foo( … )` call site, not at the `A( … )` call site. The forwarding constructor will thus be preferred over a perhaps more suitable constructor that requires a conversion. And braced-init-lists can't be a template-deduced argument, whereas they will work for inheriting constructors. And you can't do this for multiple bases, although that seldom happens anyway.

This should work with C-style variadic lists or anything else… although depending on your compiler version, perfect forwarding in such corner cases may also be a touchy issue.

Comment: In my code I happen to have many constructors, not just the 1 I listed in this example.  Which is why I was trying to simplify the derived classes.  I'll read up on perfect forwarding.  Thanks for the code example.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several different approaches to this:

1. Use variadic templates or emulate them.
2. Use templates with mixin types.
3. Make `Foo` a template class.
4. Avoid C-style variadic constructors.

Here's a spoiler: I would advice to avoid C-style variadic constructors. For people who want quick answers, it would be enough to just read that point below.

### Variadic templates

The code would look like this

```
class A : virtual public Foo
{
public:
    template <typename Ts>
    explicit A( Ts&&...ts ) : Foo( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ) {}
};
```

All arguments that `A::A` receives are simply forwarded to the constructor of `Foo`. In effect it's the same as the inheriting constructor. Unfortunately, neither VS10 nor VS11 support variadic templates yet. But there's a way to emulate this:

```
class A : virtual public Foo
{
public:
    template <typename T1>
    explicit A( T1 && t1 ) 
     : Foo( std::forward<T1>(t1)
     ) {}
    template <typename T1
            , typename T2>
    A( T1 && t1
     , T2 && t2 ) 
     : Foo( std::forward<T1>(t1)
          , std::forward<T2>(t2) 
     ) {}
    template <typename T1
            , typename T2
            , typename T3>
    A( T1 && t1
     , T2 && t2
     , T3 && t3 ) 
     : Foo( std::forward<T1>(t1)
          , std::forward<T2>(t2) 
          , std::forward<T3>(t3) 
     ) {}
    // and so forth, until a certain limit
};
```

I know this is ugly. But even the standard library implementation uses this bloaty technique. Probably, you don't want to do that for every exception class you write. Instead you can do this with a template class which does the implementation for you, as I will show now.

### Templates with mix-in types

To avoid the code bloat above for every class, you can instead let a template class do the work for you:

```
template <typename Mixin>
class FooImpl : virtual public Foo, public Mixin
{
public:
    template <typename Ts>
    explicit FooImpl( Ts&&...ts ) 
        : Foo( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ), Mixin() {}        
};
```

You put the new functionality of your class `A` into a mix-in class `AMixin` and then you can write

```
typedef FooImpl<AMixin> A;
```

and you get the desired functionality. Of course, since you don't have variadic templates you have to use some bloaty code once. But it's only once. Also, if you'd like you can let the mix-in class inherit virtually from `Foo`, if you need that classes functionality:

```
class AMixin : virtual public Foo
{
    AMixin() : Foo( "" ) {}
    // new functionality
};
```

Virtual inheritance has the nice side-effect here, that the most derived class decides which constructor of `Foo` is called. In our case that would be the `FooImpl` template class. Hence, don't worry about the `Foo( "" )`.

### Make `Foo` a template class

Another approach would be to make `Foo` a template class which does the implementation.

```
template <typename Tag>
class Foo : public std::exception
{
public:
    Foo( const char * s, ... );
    // other functionality
};

typedef Foo<struct ATag> A;
typedef Foo<struct BTag> B;
```

This approach has several draw-backs to the mix-in approch:

- You don't have a common base. You can't catch a `Foo` exception, but only specific derived classes.
- You can't add functionality to the derived classes using mix-in classes.

The second point might not be so bad, since you can extend your Foo class to cover functionality if you'd like. The type is often enough information for the user of an exception class. For the first point there's a solution. Create a common base class for the `Foo` template classes which inherits `std::exception`:

```
class AbstractFoo : public std::exception
{
public:
    // other functionality from above, 
    // possibly some pure virtual functions.
    // constructors will be generated by the compiler.
};

template <typename Tag>
class Foo : public AbstractFoo
{
public:
    Foo( const char * s, ... );
    // other functionality
};

typedef Foo<struct ATag> A;
typedef Foo<struct BTag> B;
```

Now the client code can catch `AbstractFoo` which is a common base for the template instantiations. Note that the client must catch by reference in this case. This is a good thing, because this is the way to do it correctly. (Otherwise, you get into type slicing trouble.)

### Avoid C-style variadic constructors

C-style variadic functions are not typesafe. Especially in error-handling code which is typically the least tested code this is something to avoid, because it is error prone (you get run-time errors instead of compile-time errors). Therefore, prefer programming techniques which generate compile-time errors and avoid these variadic constructors all together. Instead of passing a variadic number of arguments you might as well just pass an `std::string`. The caller can easily put the string together:

```
// Your code
class Foo : public std::exception
{
    Foo( std::string message );
    // other stuff
};

// client code
if ( error )
    throw Foo( "Could not open file '" + fileName + "'." );
```

Derived classes can simply forward their `std::string` argument to their base class `Foo`. The client code looks clean and simple without this C-style formatting list with `"%s"` which I personally find ugly. Possibly you have some objection to this approach:

- *What if I want to print some numbers?* Well, then use `std::to_string(i)`.
- *What if an exception is thrown during the construction of the string?* That is possible, but highly unlikely. What kind of exceptions could be thrown? Possibly a `std::bad_alloc`? I can't think of anything else. For the construction of some string there are a few bytes to be allocated on the heap. Very unlikely, that an exception is thrown. But think about it: This can also happen in the variadic implementation, even when you don't use anything that could possibly throw inside your class. When client code tries to throw an exception, then the exception is conceptually copied to some undefined place (according to the C++ standard). This undefined place can be the heap (certainly it's not the stack) and can run out of memory in which case -- you guessed it -- an `std::bad_alloc` is thrown instead of your exception. So you can't avoid the possibility of an exception being thrown in client code during exception creation or copying.

My advise: Just take an `std::string` as constructor argument. That's the way `std::runtime_error` works. You might also consider to derive from `std::runtime_error` instead of `std::exception` directly, since it meaningfully implements the `what()` function.

Comment: Variadic template constructors are fine. C-style variadic lists are unsafe. This might be clearer before the section at the bottom.

Comment: Good idea. I'll change it.